# c# WPF prevent splashscreen (image -> buildaction -> Splashscreen) on special parameter startup

Tags: c#, wpf, splash-screen

In my c# wpf application i added a splashscreen with the build in splashscreen method:
I set the special setting "BuildAction" of an resource image to "SplashScreen"

Is there a way to prevent the Splashscreen from displaying on, lets say, a special parameter.
In other words - if i start my application without parameter, i would like to display the Splashscreen.
If i start the Application with the parameter "minimized" i would like to prevent the display of the Splashscreen.

Is there another way to handle this, instead of creating my own custom "fake" splashscreen?

kindly regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i just solved the question by myself:

instead of set the build action of an image to SplashScreen i set the splash screen programmatically in the App.xaml.cs (void App_Startup) - where i also have to handle the parameterized startup:

```
        SplashScreen oSplashScreen = new SplashScreen("Resources\\splash-screen.jpg");

        if (!bMinimizedStartup)
        {
            oSplashScreen.Show(true, true);
        }
```

googled the answer from http://kentb.blogspot.ch/2012/12/wpf-splash-screens.html